# display nodes dfs algorithm depth

Tags: graph-algorithm

during the creation of the adjacent nodes I have created a vector from where to view the adjacent nodes until you reach the destination node but when you create do not understand why because I delete it at the end.

vettore_nuovo_percorso =

```
 1     2     4     5
```

vettore_nuovo_percorso =

```
 1     2     4     5
```

nodi =

```
 1     2     4     5
```

ans =

```
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 0     2     4     2     2     2     2
 0     0     0     3     4     4     4
 0     0     0     0     0     3     5
```

nodi_sorgenti =

```
 3     5
```

nodi_sorgenti =

```
 3     5

'BLACK'

'BLACK'

'BLACK'

'BLACK'

'BLACK'
```

ans =

```
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 0     2     4     2     2     2     2
 0     0     0     3     4     4     4
 0     0     0     0     0     3     5
```

conta_nodo_trovato =

```
 1
```

crucial aspect of the code
vector path should not vanish

vettore_nuovo_percorso =

```
 []
```

nodi =

```
 []
```

ans =

```
 1     1     1
 0     2     4
```

nodi_sorgenti =

```
 2     4
```

nodi_sorgenti =

```
 2     4

'BLACK'

'BLACK'

'WHITE'

'BLACK'

'WHITE'
```

ans =

```
 1     1     1
 0     2     4



          function [vertice,nodi]=DFS_Visit(edges,vertices,self,nodi_visitati,vb,conta_impo_colore,conta_nodo_trovato)
```

%con un ciclo copio sul vettore nodi_sorgenti tutte le destinazioni
%raggiugibili da dove poi viene passatto come terzo parametro alla chiamata
%DFS_Visit(edges,vertices,self,nodi_visitati,vb,conta_impo_colore,conta_nodo_trovato)

```
    for j6=1:length(nodi_visitati)


       vertices.conta_righe=vertices.conta_righe+1;


%copio tutte le possibili destinazioni sul vettore
%percorso solo una volta

 display(vertices.conta_righe);

if vertices.conta_righe==1


for j=1:length(nodi_visitati)



   self.vettore_percorso(vertices.conta_righe,j)=nodi_visitati(j6);

        display(self.vettore_percorso);

     end

     end

     [n1,m1]=size(self.vettore_percorso);


       for j2=1:m1
```

%prelevo la sorgente
           if nodi_visitati(j6)==self.vettore_percorso(n1,j2)

```
  if nodi_visitati(j6)~=vb


conta_edge=0;

  conta_nodi_sorgenti=0;



   %dimensione riga e colonna


[n1,m1]=size(self.vettore_percorso);         



   display(self.vettore_percorso);

%se esiste prelevo tutte le destinazioni del nodo


   edges2=ver.connectedEdges(edges,nodi_visitati(j6));


    for j8=1:length(edges2)

   %contatore nodi sorgenti
```

%inserimento destinzioni nel vettore nodi_sorgenti

```
conta_nodi_sorgenti=conta_nodi_sorgenti+1;
    nodi_sorgenti(conta_nodi_sorgenti)=edges2(j8);
```

if nodi_sorgenti(conta_nodi_sorgenti)==vb

```
indice=conta_nodi_sorgenti;
end

%copio in un vettore in una nuova riga e nella stessa colonna il valore
%della destinazione


display('edg');


display(edges2);



     end



   [n2,m2]=size(self.vettore_percorso);         

    %copio sul vettore tutti i  valori pari a
     %valore delle destinazioni nella colonna j2
       %trovata  da dove risiede la sorgente trovata



       if self.vettore_percorso(n1,j2)~=vb
             for k=1:n2

          for j=1:length(edges2)

             self.vettore_percorso(k,m2+j)=self.vettore_percorso(k,j2);
           display(self.vettore_percorso);

                                      end
       if k==n2

        for k3=1:length(edges2)

    %copio su tutti
       %ivettori le
        %destinazioni
           %ragggiungibili
           %sul vettore
          %self.vettore_percorso

    self.vettore_percorso(n2+1,m2+k3)=edges2(k3);
                                                  end
                                      end

                            end

                            end




  end                           








                       end




                               end

    end















     [n,m]=size(self.vettore_percorso);

%chiamata della funzione DFS

for j=1:length(nodi_sorgenti)

      if nodi_sorgenti(j)~=vb




      self.conta_v=1;

display(conta_visita);

  display('nkl');


         display(conta_visita);

       display(nodi_sorgenti);



      else

          self.conta_v=0;

      end

end
       if self.conta_v==0


      DFS.DFS_Visit(edges,vertices,self,nodi_sorgenti,vb,conta_impo_colore,0);



end


end









   %copio sul vettore tutte i percorsi fino a raggiungere
       %la destinazione


    [n3,m3]=size(self.vettore_percorso);



     for j3=1:m3


if self.vettore_percorso(j4,j3)==vb


     conta_nodo_trovato=1;



[n3,m3]=size(self.vettore_percorso);         



display('j3');
     conta_visita=1;
display(j3);

conta_percorso=conta_percorso+1;   
    for j7=1:m3


        if j7==j3
                for j8=1:n3
vettore_nuovo_percorso(conta_percorso,j8)=self.vettore_percorso(j8,j3);
              display(vb);

  end


        end

    end                             





                                                 end                                     



                                                       end




    end
```

Comment: Hi, during the creation of the adjacent nodes I have created a vector from where to view the adjacent nodes until you reach the destination node but when you create do not understand why because I delete it at the end.

Comment: I am sorry, this is both badly formatted and unclear. I expect you will not get any help. Can you edit this so that the code is all formatted as code? And can you please give an example of what you expect and what you actually got? That might help us to understand.

Comment: of the code vector path should not vanish,non lo posso formattare tutto, e semplice da capire. Thanks

Comment: That is some extremely unreadable code there... Looks like maybe its supposed to be `perl`, but I wouldn't swear to that...